# create a new job with different name from backup of existing SSIS job and multiple database name in ssis config file

Tags: ssis, jobs

I would like to create new job by copy from existing job and point the new job to another database. I tried to find out the the steps and did not find any suitable steps for this.

One thing I know is: this can be done using "script job as" -> "create to". and then changing the name of the job.

However, is there any other step needs to be taken care? How can I points to a different DB? Can I make my connection string in config by adding two data source[like we can add multiple email with comma separated]?

something like this:

```
 <InitialCatalog>Systest1,Systest2</InitialCatalog>
```

Do I need to change the SSIS config file?

Please give me some tutorial for this or few steps that may help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parametrize your connection manager in the package you are running and pass the connection string from the agent job. Then you can have two jobs that run the same package on different databases.

To parametrize the connection manager, right-click on it and select "Parametrize" from the pop-up menu.

Comment: I'm thinking to change config file and would be easy and quick. I'm not sure now, if my development PC is correctly configured to handle this change.Moreover, there are multiple SSIS packages [one calling another]...